# Pass Props and Access Object Values in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm kinda new to JS and React and I'm trying to acomplish something interesting so at the Parent Component I have an array/object with color and bg hex values, and a random picker as a constant, so what I want to do is pas to child components to use the color and bg value, but Is not working for me.

Parent:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Home from './pages/Home'

export default function App() {
  const colors = [
    {color: '#790100', bg: '#ff5a50'},
    {color: '#700a4b', bg: '#f596d3'},
    {color: '#ffc9ba', bg: '#fec9b9'},
  ]
  const getRanColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

  const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: ${getRandomQuote.bg};
  color: ${getRandomQuote.color}`
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Wrapper>
          <Route key="home" globalColor={getRanColor} path="/" component={Home} exact />
        </Wrapper>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Child:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
export default function Home({globalColor}) {
    const Title = styled.div`
    background: ${globalColor.bg};
    color: ${globalColor.color};`
    return (
        <>
            <Title>Learning React in root.</Title>
        </>
    )
}
```

So I's not working, I've seen some tutorials and they tend to do like this somehow, but I just can't get rid of the error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'bg' and 'color' of undefined.

Comment: You have both APIs wrong, you define styled component on every render, and you don't use `useParam`, please read the docs beforehand

Comment: @DennisVash can you explain more about the styled components what I'm doing wrong, and how to useParams,;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `render props` instead `component props` to pass props to your child component:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Home from './pages/Home'

export default function App() {
  const colors = [
    {color: '#790100', bg: '#ff5a50'},
    {color: '#700a4b', bg: '#f596d3'},
    {color: '#ffc9ba', bg: '#fec9b9'},
  ]
  const getRanColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

  const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: ${getRandomQuote.bg};
  color: ${getRandomQuote.color}`
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Wrapper>
          <Route key="home" path="/" render={() => <Home globalColor={getRanColor}/>} exact />
        </Wrapper>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: Getting an error, can you show now how to handle the param at the child component?

Comment: Your child component is fine, can you please show me the error!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a `globalColor` parameter into your `<Route>` component, not your `<Home>`. You need to use **render props** instead:

```js
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Home from './pages/Home'

export default function App() {
  const colors = [
    {color: '#790100', bg: '#ff5a50'},
    {color: '#700a4b', bg: '#f596d3'},
    {color: '#ffc9ba', bg: '#fec9b9'},
  ]
  const getRanColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

  const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: ${getRandomQuote.bg};
  color: ${getRandomQuote.color}`
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Wrapper>
          // Use a `render` prop here
          <Route key="home" path="/" render={(props) => (<Home globalColor={getRanColor} {...props} />)} exact />
        </Wrapper>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

This will get the `globalColor` prop into the Home component where you want it, which can be accessed with `this.props.globalColor`.

As a side note, there's two places in your parent component `App()` where you're using `getRandomQuote` instead of `getRanColor`. This is not a fix for your specific question, but it will cause your styles to not work properly and may throw an error.